# difference putting statement in the () in (function{}) and putting statement inside the(function{})

Tags: javascript

I am using Immediately-Invoked Function Expression to use `setTimeout` in `while` loop.

This is my code:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let x = 0;
while(x<10){
    (function(x){
    setTimeout(function(){
        div.textContent =x;
    },1000*x)
})(x++)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
  (function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.textContent = x;
    }, 1000 * x)
    x++;
  })()
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The code works fine, but I just curious why my second codes doesn't work and will make the page either become unresponsive or doesn't work at all.

I do check several answer about IIFE like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript), but seems not solving my problem.

Could anyone explain me the difference putting `x++` in the () and putting `x++` inside the function?

What is the difference between them?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: not sure what you mean my make the page become unresponsive. It just makes the text jump straight to 10 - and yes I can explain why it does this but not in the working example. (It's to do with the scope of `x`.) I guess this is what you mean by "doesn't work at all" but that's not very precise. As for unresponsive, as I said - no idea where you're getting that from.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, not sure if it is my problem, but sometimes I run my second code, the page just keep loadind and loading and finally become unresponsive

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `x` refers to different things in both examples when performing `div.textContent =x;`. Starting with your second example first, the value of `x` when performing `div.textContent =x;` is obtained from the outer scope of your `setTimeout` callback function, ie, your global `let x = 0;` declaration:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let x = 0; <-----------------+
while (x < 10) {             |
  (function() {              |
    setTimeout(function() {  |
      div.textContent = x; --+
    }, 1000 * x)
    x++;
  })()
}
```

The above loop iterates 10 times, each iteration it:

1. Invokes the IIFE
2. When the IIFE runs, it queues a callback using `setTimeout()`. This callback is only run after your synchronous `while()` loop has completed all of its iterations
3. Increments `x` after queuing your setTimeout calls.

Point is 2 is the main point here. Because all of your callback functions queued by each `setTimeout()` call are only invoked after your `while` loop has completed, `x` at the time that your callback executes will be set to `10`. As outlined above, your callback functions all refer to the `x` declared in the global scope (which is now `10`), and so your HTML content will only update with the value of `10`.

For your second example, your `x` refers to the argument of the IIFE, and not the globally declared variable. When you invoke your IIFE, you're passing in the current value of `x` that you're iterated on and then incrementing it (with `x++`). This allows the body of the IIFE to have its own independent "copy" of `x` that is scoped locally to the IIFE body, and can't be accessed from outside the IIFE. The callback in the setTimeout() references this local version of the `x` and not the global one. It might be clearer if you call the formal parameter of your IIFE something other than `x` (such as `y`) to highlight that incrementing `x` from the outer scope doesn't influence the `x` from within the inner scope of IIFE:

```
while(x<10){
  (function(y){ <------------+
    setTimeout(function(){   |
      div.textContent =y; ---+
    },1000*x)
  })(x++)
}
```

For each iteration of the `while` loop:

1. You invoke your IIFE, passing in the value of `x` as an argument, and then incrementing it using `x++`
2. The IIFE runs, creating a new scope with local variables of its own. In this case `y` (in your example `x`), is local to the IIFE and takes the value of the `x` value that was passed into the function when it was called.
3. A call to `setTimeout()` queues a callback. The queued callback is only after your loop has completed.

The main difference in this example as opposed to the first is that the callback here references the local `y` variable for each function IIFE created. So even though the callbacks are called after your while loop has finished and the global value for `x` is now `10`, each `setTimeout()` callback will refer to the local `y` variable created when the IIFE was invoked, where `y` refers to the value of `x` for that particular iteration.

Comment: Appreciate for the detailed explanation. Just one question to the example you give (example that change x to y),  the `y` we defined in `function(y)` is a duplicate of global x and it is not a new local variable we defined, so the value of y will be changed as global x changed. Is it correct?

Comment: @James `y` _is_ the new local variable that we defined, so the value of `y` will not be changed as the global `x` is changed as `y` is a "copy" of the global `x` variable. If `y` were to change as the global `x` changes, then you would see the same issue with all the values being `10`, but that doesn't happen, as `y` isn't changed by anything in the above code, it is only read